# py2exe - executable does not start

Tags: matplotlib, py2exe

I've compiled my app with this script in order to avoid compiling error on libmzq and MSVCP90 dlls:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=[{"script": "Int_assortimenti.py"}],
       options = {
        "py2exe": {
            "dll_excludes": ["libzmq.dll", "MSVCP90.dll"]
        }
    })
```

I obtain my executable but when I run it the result is:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Consider that n my application matplotlib is not used.

Thanks a lot in advance: form me is crucial to solve this problem!

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, look here ("Data files" section): http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib

This might help you with that issue.

**Edit.** Oh, I'm sorry I had read your question inattentive :( If your app doesn't use matplotlib, I think you can just add it to excludes. Smth like this:

```
excludes = ['matplotlib'] # add here all libraries (separated by commas) that you don't need in app

setup(console=[{"script": "Int_assortimenti.py"}],
   options = {
    "py2exe": {
        "excludes": excludes,
        "dll_excludes": ["libzmq.dll", "MSVCP90.dll"]
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, already done and resolved. But I have a problem: if I have to include in the data_file another file for the app (an image in this case) the setup file:
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import matplotlib

file_dati=[]
file_dati.append(matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())
file_dati.append(('img1','C:\Users\MZompetta.000\Desktop\20130114_assortimenti\img1.gif'))

setup(console=[{"script": "Int_assortimenti.py"}],
       options = {
        "py2exe": {
            "dll_excludes": ["libzmq.dll", "MSVCP90.dll"]
        }
    }, data_files=file_dati
)
do not function properly